# chrome gives MEDIA_ERR_DECODE on all videos when scrubbing

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, video.js

I have two PCs that when scrubbing in chrome give a MEDIA_ERR_DECODE.  One is windows 7 with chrome 26 and one is windows 8 with chrome 27.  This happens with all videos.

If I try to scrub on the videoJS home page, the same thing happens.  It scrubs for a while and then the screen goes gray with the spinning blobs.  So I know it's not my code.

The only thing in common is the videoJS is being used.  I am trying to find some other website that allows scrubbing to test on.  Youtube doesn't.  It just shows some useless gallery of frames.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is similar to an error we have been hearing reports of at Vimeo with HTML5 video playback.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=180695